# How do I aggregate multiple columns with one function in pandas when using groupby?

Tags: python, pandas, aggregate

I have a data frame with a "group" variable, a "count" variable, and a "total" variable. For each group I want to sum the count column and divide that by the sum of the total column. How do I do this, ideally in one line of code?

Here is an example to work with:

```
test_dc = {1:{'group':'A','cnt':3,'total':5},
           2:{'group':'B','cnt':1,'total':8},
           3:{'group':'A','cnt':2,'total':4},
           4:{'group':'B','cnt':6,'total':13}
          }
test_df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(test_dc, orient='index')
```

Expected output (roughly):

```
group | average
    A | 0.55555
    B | 0.33333
```

Edit: changed column name from "count" to "cnt" because there seems to be an existing `count()` method on groupby objects.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `DataFrame.groupby` to group by a column, and then call `sum` on that to get the sums.

```
>>> df = test_df
    .groupby('group')
    .sum()
>>> df      
       count  total
group              
A          5      9
B          7     21
```

Then you can grab the column and divide them through to get your answer.

```
>>> df['count'] / df['total']
    group
A    0.555556
B    0.333333
dtype: float64
```

You can do this in one line by taking advantage of the `DataFrame.pipe` operator:

```
test_df
    .groupby('group')
    .sum()
    .pipe(lambda df: df['count'] / df['total'])
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd use a combination of `agg` and `eval`

```
test_df.groupby('group').agg('sum').eval('cnt / total')

group
A    0.555556
B    0.333333
dtype: float64
```